# Using WHERE, GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I have a table `RacesTimes` with columns `RaceID` and `TotalTime`, how I can retrieve the lowest `TotalTime` for every `RaceID` ?

I tried (few other variations too, but no result)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `RacesTimes` 
GROUP BY `RaceID` 
ORDER BY `TotalTime` ASC
```

but it gives me the first inserted row from that `RaceID`, not the lowest `TotalTime` row from that `RaceID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(TotalTime), RaceID
FROM RacesTimes
GROUP BY RaceID
ORDER BY MIN(TotalTime) ASC
```

Note that MySQL allows the syntax you did have: other RDBMS do not.

This says "give me minimum TotalTime per RacedID"

Comment: Thanks ! But I need other thing too: I want to select all from that minimum row, can you modify that query ? I tried but it selected from the first inserted row.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733284/usage-of-group-by-and-min-with-hsqldb/16733382#16733382 THis is HSQL but the same idea applies (my last query there)

Comment: I did what you said there: SELECT ANY( RaceID ), MIN( TotalTime ), RaceID FROM RacesTimes GROUP BY RaceID but it gives me "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( RaceID ), MIN( TotalTime ), RaceID FROM RacesTimes GROUP BY RaceID ' at line 1", maybe it doesn't recognizes ANY function.

Comment: @NistorConstantin: MySQL does not have ANY. I meant my 3rd query sorry. ANY was added in an edit. Oops

Answer (score 1):

You need an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), specifically [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min):

```
SELECT RaceID, MIN(TotalTime)
FROM RaceTimes
GROUP BY RaceID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have few others columns too in the table, how I can extract them all (using the MIN column grouped) ?